# Linking to Boost Regex library in VS2012

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2012, linker, firebreath

I'm trying to build my VS2012 C++ project using Boost Regex library. It seems that the linker does not find the library and gives the error:

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc110-mt-gd-1_50.lib'
```

In "Project Properties:Linker:General:Additional Library Directories", I included a path which (within a subdirectory) contains a library named **`boost_regex.lib`**.

This was built by a 3rd party framework (FireBreath), and I shouldn't change it. How do I get VS2012 to use this library instead of looking for one under the name referenced in the error?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, what makes you so sure that the boost_regex.lib is the right one? Is it even for your compiler and version? I also doubt that it is for the debug variant of the runtime library. My guess is that you will have to build this for the compiler that you're using and properly install it, for which there are instructions at the Boost website. This might also imply rebuilding FireBreath for your compiler, assuming that's a C++ library, too.

Then, the code in Boost that detects compiler settings and then selects a library to link against is correct for normal setups. This code uses "#pragma comment(lib, ...)" to specify the lib to link with, so you should be able to find the code. There, you should also be able to detect the macros that turn this feature off. However, you are probably not fixing anything with that but rather you are creating more problems.

Comment: The library was build in VS2012 based on the projects generated by FireBreath, so it should be the correct one.

Comment: @dbkk it's probably best to learn how to compile Boost yourself

Comment: Somehow complete boost build from source does not have *lib* prefix in library names, that is `/nodefaultlib:libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib` in your project settings⇨linker⇨command line⇨additional options does the trick. Perhaps there is a glitch somewhere as how to determine  library name. If one looks for regex module with CMake, it does return correct name.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting the library is not something you want to do. Instead:

- Download Boost into, say, `c:\boost`
- Open a VS command prompt, go into `c:\boost` and run `bjam`. When this is done, run `b2`. Wait.
- Now go into your project and add `c:\boost\stage\lib` to the Additional Library Directories setting.

This will allow you to build the project.